# Move all users to your Channel (Discord JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'd like to create a command, that moves all users in my Discord voice channel. 
Here is what i tried.

```
...
client.on('message', async message =>{
    //Check message is not Bot
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.content=="!movetome"){

        if(message.member.voice.channel) {//Is user in voicechannel

            message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => { //Loop every user
                if(member.id!=message.member.id&&member.voice.channel){//Is user in voicechannel and is user the command executer
                    member.setVoiceChannel(message.member.voice.channel)//Sets user to channel
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
...
```

After I tried to run the command "!movetome" in discord chat I got the following error message:

```
(node:12268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: member.setVoiceChannel is not a function
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly this seems like a bad idea if any user can do it but regardless, `.setVoiceChannel` is v11, they moved it to `<GuildMember>.voice.setChannel()`

Change the contents inside of `if(message.content=="!movetome")` to this

```js
const channel = message.member.voice.channel;
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
  //guard clause, early return
  if(member.id === message.member.id || !member.voice.channel) return;
  member.voice.setChannel(channel);
});
```