# How to move members from the voice you are connected in, to another voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

After the command `movemepls` is typed (and provided that the person who typed the command is in a voice channel) it moves EVERY member in the same voice call, to a different voice call. So far, I've tried to use all sorts of code, but I'm not sure how to return, specifically, each member in the given vc (the person who typed the command)

1. How to check that the person who typed the command is in a voice call?
2. How to return all members in the given VC?
3. How to bulk move all the members to the new given channel?

```js
bot.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'movemepls') {
    voice_channel = '768348175437922324'
    msg.member.voice.setChannel('insert channelID here')

    voice_channel.members.forEach(function (guildMember, guildMemberId) {
      console.log(guildMemberId, guildMember.user.username);
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Have you looked around? Since I have found some:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62637725/user-connected-to-voice-channel and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62378011/move-all-users-to-your-channel-discord-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic example of how you could do it, you can extend it to whatever you want:

```js
bot.on("message", async message => {

   if(message.content.startsWith("movemepls") {
     let args = message.content.slice(9).trim().split(/ +/g);
     let voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
     let moveTo = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'voice').find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() === args.slice(0).join(" ").toLowerCase());

     if(voiceChannel) {
       message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
       if(!member.voice.channel) return;
       member.voice.setChannel(moveTo);
     })
   } else return;
  }
})
```

Usage:

```
movemepls <channel name>
```

Comment: If you want a more in depth explanation just comment, then I will edit my answer.

Comment: That's good! Could you write another snippet of code that (with the same checks) would move everyone in the voice channel that I am in (the person who typed the command) to a vc that I specify?

Comment: If I understood that right, this is exactly what it does. If you type <prefix>movemepls <vc name> everyone that is in your current vc, and you, gets moved to a vc you specify by typing the name of it in the command.

Comment: Could you post the full code with the command as well? Im not sure how to enable arguments as well

Comment: @Shreyas007 I didn't test it, but it should work. Edited my answer.

Comment: Well do I dont have a prefix set like ! or , so is it possible to do it without it? (Coudl you redo the code)

Comment: @Shreyas007 Oh sorry my bad. Edited my answer again.